# Setting time delay in logstash forwarder

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder, elastic-stack

So recently I set up ELK stack with logstash forwarder located on two EC2 instances that forwards server logs to elasticsearch and kibana installed on another EC2 instance. Right after doing that, I recognized that the server CPU percentage keeps going up dramatically with the top process always being java (It is logstash-forwarder because the server is written in node.js).

I thought about limiting the number of requests logstash-forwarder sends per minute. But first, I'm not sure if that is even doable from logstash-forwarder configuration. And secondly, if it is doable, is it better to send a bulk of log data rather at a one go rather than sending small chunks continuously?

Thanks.

Comment: logstash-forwarder is written in go and compiles down to a native binary.  Are you sure it's logstash-forwarder and not logstash that you are running?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the servers that has high CPU are the ones running logstash-forwarder. The logstash and elasticsearch instance is working just fine.

Comment: Neither Logstash, logstash-forwarder, or Elasticsearch is written in Node.js, and Node.js doesn't run on the JVM anyway. First find out what process is spiking in CPU usage. If it's a Java process it's not logstash-forwarder.

Comment: I've never mentioned that either of logstash, logstash-forwarder and elasticsearch are written in node.js. If you had spent more time reading the question you would find out that I said the top process is Java and the server is written in node.js